# KeyError: 'kivy.garden.graph'

Tags: python, kivy, python-3.7

I just started on kivy recently but when I import from kivy.garden.graph import MeshLinePlot  it gives an error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
     from kivy.garden.graph import MeshLinePlot
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 668, in _load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 640, in _load_backward_compatible
 KeyError: 'kivy.garden.graph'
```

I have installed Kivy using there installation guide for windows https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to install kivy-garden module first:

```
pip install kivy-garden
```

Then install graph package from garden module:

```
garden install graph
```

See https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.garden.html

Answer (score 4):

You should install matplotlib if you didn´t

if the above doesn't work or still output Key Error kivy.garden.matplotlib

You should type the following in your command window

```
garden install matplotlib
```

[I have already installed it you can view the picture here am using matplotlib 3.1.1 python 3.7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4AWMO.png)

Comment: Well I had the same problem yesterday and matplotlib was installed in my i tried uninstalling and installing still the same, until i saw a post in this  [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/kivy/comments/5h8dx9/install_kivygarden_matplotlib/) but it gave me an error saying key Error **key Error kivy.garden.matplotlib** and then i tried  **garden install matplotlib** which fixed my problem

Answer (score 4):

They have changed the installation method to `pip install kivy_garden.graph`
https://github.com/kivy-garden/graph

You should execute this, and then proceed to `%python\Lib\site-packages\kivy_garden`
Copy the `\graph` folder inside to this directory `%python\Lib\site-packages\kivy\garden`

This solved the issue for me.

- Python 3.8.1

Answer (score 0):

If you find the above error in the Android log file when trying to compile deploy and run the Kivy app on Android using buildozer, then try this solution: https://github.com/kivy/buildozer/issues/1226

And remember to put matplotlib in the buildozer.spec requirements. Something like this, depending on your specific needs:

requirements = python3,kivy,pillow,matplotlib